# URSINA No module named 'direct'

Tags: python, ursina

(sorry for my English), i'm trying to use ursina on visual studio but when i run my code the IDE show a file: texture.py and and in particular the error: no module named 'direct'
I try to install direct but there are other error and i don't understand why for me this module is necessary and in internet i don't found of it nothing.

thanks for the help

sorry,[the start of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5TM6.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf9a5.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaugh.png)

Comment: please edit your question and add the code that is causing the issue as well as the error traceback, as text, and explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: we can't see your code, we can't see FULL error message, and we can't read in your mind - so we also don't understand why you have problem.  You have to describe all details in question. At this moment we can only downvote and/or close question.

Answer (score 1):

`direct` is part of `panda3d`, which is a dependency of `ursina`. I suggest making sure it installed correctly. Maybe try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

It seems panda3d is not correctly installed. Direct is part of panda3d and ursina is made over panda3d, so if direct is not correctly installed, then ursina will not run.

I recommend you to reinstall ursina and panda3d (latest version):

- replace pip with your pip version/command
- sudo is optional

```py
(sudo) pip3 install ursina
(sudo) pip3 install panda3d
```

If you want the latest version of ursina, you can do `(sudo) pip install git+https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina.git`

Best wishes, Lixt

Answer (score 0):

thank you very very much, my probem was that with pip panda3d have some problems end i decided to install it by the online site and now my program go.
i never thought that the problem was in panda3d(that contain direct) installation.